# Is it possible to transfer data through NFC from Iphone to Android?

Tags: iphone, nfc, phonegap, data-transfer, apache-cordova

I'm thinking on developing a web-app using PhoneGap to transfer data from one platform to the other. As I understand NFC core for iphone lets you read tags but is there any way for it to transfer and receive data from an Android device?